# KML / Google Earth Limit on number / complexity of InnerBoundaryIs polygons

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Is there a limitation on the number of inner polygons GE can display?
The KML file is at:
http://www.gmapsapi.net/kml/westyard280.kml

When displayed in Google Earth, some of the inner polygons or islands
are skewed (for lack of better terminology).

The KML displays correctly in Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a limit on the number of inner polygons. You do, however, have a few polygons where the boundaries (inner and outer) intersect each other and most of your boundaries seem to be self intersecting. While that isn't a violation of the KML specification, it will trigger warnings if your run it through a validator, since the renderer used in different KML clients (e.g. Earth vs Maps) can have different requirements on the topology of the polygons it renders. I believe what you are seeing is artifacts from the triangulation approach that Earth uses.

I would add a step to your workflow to simplify any polygons you want to display. Most GIS software, open source and not, can do this just fine. Simplification may also help with performance, as this is quite a large number of coordinates. Usually you can set a flag for how you want fill simplification to proceed, and you can select the fill rule (like that of Google Maps) that fills in the way you desire.

Comment: Thanks Brendan for your suggestion and analysis. I had previously handled all polygons as outer polygons and filled the "inner" polygons with "yellow".  I can live with the fill color, i.e., doesn't have to void of color as an inner polygon.